# Powershell Command: rm -rf

Tags: powershell, command, cmd, rm

`rm` is to remove item, but what is the parameter `-rf` do or signify?

---

Whenever I typed help -rf it printed the entire list of available commands in powershell.  What happens if you type `rm -rf` in powershell? From reading around I've gathered that it will delete everything on the drive?  I'm not sure?

Also, is `rm -rf` same as `rm -rf /`?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

PowerShell isn't UNIX. `rm -rf` is UNIX shell code, not PowerShell scripting.

- This is the documentation for `rm` (short for `Remove-Item`) [on PowerShell](http://ss64.com/ps/remove-item.html).
- This is the documentation for `rm` [on UNIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/rm.html).

See the difference?

On UNIX, `rm -rf` alone is invalid. You told it what to do via `rm` for *remove* with the attributes `r` for *recursive* and `f` for *force*, but you didn't tell it what that action should be done on. `rm -rf /path/to/delete/` means `rm` (*remove*) with attributes `r` (*recursive*) and `f` (*force*) on the directory `/path/to/remove/` and its sub-directories.

The correct, equivalent command on PowerShell would be:

```
rm C:\path\to\delete -r -fo
```

Note that `-f` in PowerShell is ambiguous for `-Filter` and `-Force` and thus `-fo` needs to be used.

Comment: For completeness, the PowerShell equivalent would be `rm \ -r -f`.  You can abbreviate parameter names in PowerShell, but you can't stack them.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If you do `rm <path> -r -f` in PowerShell, but the path does not exist, an exception is thrown. In unix, if you run `rm -rf <path>` on a path which does not exist, the command exits successfully. The two commands are not equivalent.

Comment: The PowerShell equivalent is (no longer?) true. If you do that you will receive an error `Remove-Item : Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'f' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Filter -Force.` You can use `rm C:\path\to\delete -r -fo` however.

Comment: The PowerShell command does not work. When I try `rm path\to\delete -r -fo` I get error message: Remove-Item: Cannot remove item path\to\delete: The directory is not empty. : 'path\to\delete'
I am using PS version 7.1.1

Comment: I found out why (where) the PS command does not work. If I try it in a folder handled by OneDrive it fails, but it works otherwise. Microsoft please fixit!

Comment: and if (when) you get permissions errors, see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43767793/you-require-permission-from-myself-to-delete-folder-how-to-fix  (shut down applications that may have a lock on the files/folders you're trying to delete).

Answer (score 49):

You have to use:

```
Remove-Item C:\tmp -Recurse -Force
```

or (short)

```
rm C:\tmp -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: So.. waht does rm -rf / does in powershell?

Comment: Gotcha, you didn't specify at first, so I wasn't sure.

Answer (score 6):

This is the one-liner that behaves like `rm -rf`. It first checks for the existence of the path and then tries removing it.

```
if (Test-Path ./your_path) { rm -r -force ./your_path}
```

Comment: Thank you that's the right answer I was looking for. Many people forget that UNIX's -f actually allows to silently ignore a nonexistent directory.