# Terraform Destroy with Istio module

Tags: windows, macos, terraform, istio, destroy

We are using Terraform in a project where we implemented an Istio module.
Whenever we run the `terraform destroy` command, the Istio module runs a `rm -rf` command.

This works fine on Mac machines, on windows machines this causes errors.

For reference, the command is called inside the istio module and is outside of our codebase.

```
module "istio" {
  source  = "combinator-ml/istio/k8s"
}
```

Anyone run into this issue and has a workaround?

Comment: You would file this as a bug with the module's issue tracker. If the module is unmaintained, then you could fork it and develop the fix there.

Comment: You have mentioned: "on the windows machines this causes errors". Which errors? Please add this information to the question.

Comment: rm simply doesnt exist on windows machines, but we have found a workaround after contacting the devs

Comment: Please paste your workaround as an answer.

Comment: We opted to use a bash terminal on our windows machines to run our terraform commands instead, even a git bash terminal for example worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using git bash on our windows machines as a workaround

Answer (score 1):

> The istio module runs a rm -rf command.
> This works fine on the Mac machines, on the windows machines this causes errors.

This works as expected. macOS is UNIX-based system and `rm -rf` command works. Windows (powershell) doesn't have this command.

The correct, equivalent command on PowerShell would be:

```
rm C:\path\to\delete -r -fo
```

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443891/powershell-command-rm-rf). There is a very good explanation of this situation.

Back to your problem. If you are using Windows (Powershell) you need to create your custom solution (Powershell script) to delete the appropriate files using Powershell commands.